# How to export Scheduled Tasks configuration

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I'm running Windows 2012 R2 Server and I run a lot of Scheduled Tasks.
I am afraid that in case something would happened to server and I should create another server I won't be able to restore those Tasks.
Hence here's my question:
Could I somehow safe or better export Scheduled Tasks configuration in order to restore it on the same or another server?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I export Scheduled Tasks in order to restore them on the same or another server?

The [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1334529/337631) suggests exporting them one by one. There is a slightly easier method:

> All the Tasks created in Windows are stored in the Task Folder of
>   Windows System Directory which in my case is
>   C:\Windows\System32\Tasks.
>
> - Navigate to Tasks Folder.
> - Here you will see a couple of folders with some files inside it. They represent the same folder structure of the Task Scheduler and
>     files have same name too.
>
>   [image: Windows Task Scheduler Folder Structure]
> - Now copy the task files to the machine you want to export to. You can also use it to backup your tasks in case your computer needs a re
>     installation,  so you don’t have to create again.
> - Now rename the files with extension as .XML, this is the same extension used when you export the tasks using the Task Scheduler
>     Interface.
> - Once renamed, now use the Task Scheduler Import task feature to import them one by one as Windows will not recognize them if you drop
>     them directly into the Tasks Folder of Windows.

Source [How to mass export Tasks from Windows Task Scheduler](http://www.technospot.net/blogs/how-to-mass-export-tasks-from-windows-task-scheduler/)

Comment: Hi. I like this approach. Are you aware of ‘batch’ import option? I have only 20 Tasks but it would be nice to import it at once rather going one by one.

Comment: There is no batch input as stated in the answer

Answer (score 2):

### Export Scheduled Tasks Configuration for Future Restore

> ### **Manually Export Jobs**
>
> 1. Go to the scheduled tasks from **Task Scheduler** and one by one right click and select export
>
>    [image]
> 2. When the **Save As** window pops up, *navigate to a folder where you want to save that configuration* and ensure the **File name**
>      matches the job name and then press **Save**.
>
>    [image]
>
> ---
>
> ### **Manually Import/Restore Jobs**
>
> 1. Go to the **Task Scheduler** folder where you want the restored job to reside, *right click that folder* to the right and select
>      **Import**
>
>    [image]
> 2. When the **Open** window pops up, *navigate to the folder where you saved job configuration* xml file, click on that file with the
>      matching job name you want to restore, and then select **Open**.
>
>    [image]
> 3. When the **Create Task** window opens, go *through all the options to double check the various tab settings* if you want, and then press
>      **OK**. If you're prompted for security credentials at this point, just type those in just as you would have whenever you set those up
>      originally from the server you exported them from originally—security
>      context will need to be in place if needed.
>
>    [image]
>
> **Note:** *The file name of the XML file minus the `.xml` extension will be the Name of the job in Task Scheduler. If there is already a
>   job with the same name that exists in the Task Scheduler folder you
>   import it into, you will be given an error message indicating this and
>   it will not allow duplicates to be created.*
>
> Otherwise, your scheduled tasks which you exported from one server (or
>   the same server) and then imported to another server (or the same
>   server) should be in place with the same configurations, etc. just as expected.

---

### Further Resources

If you're interested in a PowerShell or scripted solution then. . .

- [Export a Scheduled Task from PowerShell](https://www.petri.com/export-scheduled-tasks-using-powershell)